# Pulling data from a webpage like Facebook

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have been googling for hours but I have yet to find an answer to this very common request.
I am trying to make an iOS app that is able to pull basic data from a website and display it in a simple UIView. What I am looking to do is exactly the same as what Facebook does when a link is entered into a message. For example:

[image]

I am new to web languages so I am looking for a detailed and simple answer as to how to do this. I'm not sure if this is an overly complicated process, maybe above my skill level, but if their are any Github libraries or any tool to help I would love to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook uses the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/). Websites add meta tags like so according to the standard...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Then a user-agent (such as your app) fetches the page, parses the meta tags and is able to display any info that the page offers.

If you're just starting to learn mobile development, one thing to keep in mind is that the phone's data connection is expensive—in terms of dollars, latency and battery life. Each round trip connection takes between 300-2000ms to complete, so you want to keep your payloads light, and issue as few requests as possible. So if you were looking to implement this for an iPhone app, you would most likely want a server or some sort of backend to do the heavy lifting.

Unfortunately I do not know of any Obj-C examples, but here is a simple example of [scraping a page and extracting OG tags](https://github.com/wyattdanger/og-lookup/blob/master/app.js) with NodeJS. From there, you would probably want to send a lightweight JSON object back to your mobile app.